# array of pointers to string , segmentation fault occurs

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, libc

I am learning pointer in c 
i have written a small program , but i am getting segmentaion fault 
i dont know where i am having the issue 
please let me know the issue with the code , it is an array of pointers to string , 
which is in a pointer to structure .

```
# include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 # include <string.h>
char   *sum(char **sol) ;
 char  *summer_sum(char*** solcs) ;
int main()
{
char* datum ="teststring";
sum(&datum);
}


char *sum(char** sol)  
{
printf("\n   value is : %s",*sol);
summer_sum(&sol);
return "1" ; 
}

char *summer_sum(char***  solcs)  
{
int i=0;
typedef struct
{
char *asg[40];
}nlist;
nlist *n1;
for( i=0 ; i<= 38 ;i++)
{ 
n1->asg[i] = calloc(1,1*sizeof(*solcs));
strcpy(n1->asg[i],**solcs);
printf("\n %d value is : %s",i,n1->asg[i]);
} 

return NULL; 
}
```

Comment: any reason to use the return type as `char *` , when that is not at all used? Also, if you are working with dynamic memories, get used to with some dynamic memory debugger tool like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: Pro tip: Don't overcomplicate things, it doesn't make you or your code any better.

Comment: Try to debug your code to see where and why the error occures?

Answer (score 1):

`n1` is used uninitialized:

```
n1->asg[i] = calloc(1,1*sizeof(*solcs));
```

On the other hand, if you want to allocate enough space for the use of `strcpy`, you must use `strlen` instead of `sizeof`

And you don't need a double or triple pointer, your code simplified:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void sum(char *sol);
char *summer_sum(char *solcs);

int main(void)
{
    char *datum = "teststring";
    sum(datum);
}

void sum(char *sol)  
{
    printf("\n   value is : %s", sol);
    summer_sum(sol);
}

char *summer_sum(char *solcs)  
{
    int i = 0;
    size_t len;
    typedef struct {
        char *asg[40];
    } nlist;

    nlist *n1 = malloc(sizeof(*n1));
    if (n1 == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    len = strlen(solcs); /* No need to compute len on each iteration */
    for (i = 0; i <= 38; i++) { /* you are filling 39 and declared 40 */
        n1->asg[i] = calloc(1, len);
        /* Always check the result of (m/c/re)alloc */
        if (n1->asg[i] == NULL) {
            perror("malloc");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        strcpy(n1->asg[i], solcs);
        printf("\n %d value is : %s", i, n1->asg[i]);
        /* Don't forget to free */
        free(n1->asg[i]);
    }
    free(n1);
    return NULL; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using your pointer `n1` uninitialized. Your program invokes **undefined behavior**. In such case you may get either expected or unexpected result.
Second, you are missing a closing brace `}` in function `summer_sum`.

Answer (score 0):

Before using `n1->`... You will have allocate memory to `n1` as well using `calloc()`

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems which involves dynamic memory allocation in your code:

1. `n1` is not initialized, you should add a statement like `n1 = malloc(sizeof(*n1));` before the `for` statement in `summer_sum()`
2. you did not allocate enough space for each `asg[i]`, you should allocate spaces for these `asg[i]` by `n1->asg[i] = malloc(strlen(**solcs) + 1);`